# register_post_type permalink

Tags: posts, permalinks, user-registration, customization

Next, I have a problem. I created a post_type = 'gallery'. 
So when I open my gallery my link goes like this:

```
localhost/gallery_name/image_name
```

but I need a structure like this:

```
localhost/post_name/gallery_name/image_name
```

In my `function php`

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/',)
```

How can save my post name(my permalink structure) and then add gallery name and image name? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use post_type_link filter. Create a handler to handle this filter, you can create $permalink as per your need there.

In addition to this, you may have to use "pre_get_posts" action also.

I used both these couple of months ago, I created permalinks to show as cpt_name/post_name.

Comment: Well,my Wordpress cant recognize post i come from,before open gallery. I even tried some of plugins,and i realize that is a problem. If i could only insert post name into the array('slug' => '/',)
that would be good. Thanks anyway